# SFSafariViewController and location

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have implemented SFSafariViewcontroller in an app. It displays a website that shows a map, like Google Maps.

If I open Google Maps in the ordinary Safari app, it will show an alert saying "Google Maps wants to user your location" [Accept][Decline]

It his question is not asked in SFSafariViewController, and the map can't be centered to the user's location.

I have tried asking location permission in the app as well (with CLLocationManager) but no luck.

Is it even possible to use the user's location in a SafariViewController, without passing URL parameters?